# SUM of bills due within a Table

Tags: database, excel, spreadsheet, finance, recurring-billing

On my previous question, I asked how to automatically tell me when my next bills are due based on today's date. Here is the link: [Display the upcoming due date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33219435/display-the-upcoming-due-date).

Once I have these bills compiled, let's say I have a series of bills in table array A2:C4, and in this series I include the type, the amount due, and the due date. I need to learn how to generate a formula that shows me the sum of bills due between pay dates, listed in B6:D6.
I have an image that show a bit of what I am trying to accomplish.
[image]

What I want to do is in Cell C8 I need to have the formula for the bills whose dates are between Cells B6 and C6. The only bill included should be the Visa, so $25 due. However, once I get paid, the next pay date will be 11/6/15, and I will need to pay the Amex bill and the MasterCard bill, so it will need to show $50 in cell C8 then. I know that there is a way to do this, but my brain hurts when I try to figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this formula:

`=SUMIFS($B$2:$B$4,$C$2:$C$4,">="&B6,C2:C4,"<"&C6)`

It's a SumIfs formula that checks to see if your date is "greater than or equal to" B6, **and** "less than to C6", meaning your date is on or after, October 23, but on or before Nov. 6 (as you have the dates in the screenshot).

edit: re-reading your question, I am slightly confused I think, but let me know how this works and what I need to change/update.

Comment: Actually Bruce, you're on the right track. The formula worked great, I added a lot more bills and calculated them to make sure it worked flawlessly and it does! works great thanks!